# Docker daemon doesn't start in minikf

Tags: kubeflow

After installing MiniKF,landing http://10.10.10.10, I use box is "arrikto/minikf" and version is '20200305.1.0',have the problem blow:

[image]

RAM have enough, disk have enough. What's wrong with it?